# Micro SD Card not able to format

Tags: filesystems, android-sdcard, protected

I have a **Micro SD Card**. I had used it in **Samsung J5 Prime**.
Once, I had rooted the **Samsung** device using **TWRP** and I had **formatted** this **SD Card** to get **access to all files** on it. The **SD Card** worked fine and still works fine in my **Samsung J5 Prime**, but other **devices** are not able to **read/write** it. Although my **Laptop** can access it (**through a Card Reader 2.0**), but it is **write-protected**, meaning that whenever I tried to **create**, **modify**, or even **delete** a file, it will **restore** back to the **same state** when I refresh the **Windows Explorer**.

**Here is my SD Card Information:** 
**FileSystem** (as shown in the Properties menu): FAT32
**Hardware Id**: SCSI\DiskHGST_____HTS545050A7E680GR2O
**Label**: F:\
**Image**: 
[image]
[image]

I tried **Windows Format tools** (**chkdsk**, **diskpart**, format option in **context menu**, in **Computer Management**), also tried **3rdParty Softwares** (**EaseUS Partition Master**), but it didn't work.
No matter how many times I clean this SD card, all files reappear again.

Even I tried to format the SD Card on **Samsung J5 Prime** itself, but that too didn't work.

**I need help to fix this. Any suggestions are much much appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SD-Card adapter (From microSD to SD) has the **Lock** protection enabled , please disable it. 
[image: Write protection]

This seems the solution, as you said

> The SD Card worked fine and still works fine in my Samsung J5 Prime, but other devices are not able to read/write it. Although my Laptop can access it, but it is write-protected, meaning that whenever I tried to create, modify, or even delete a file, it will restore back to the same state when I refresh the Windows Explorer.

Comment: there is no slide button on my sd card -_-

Comment: Does the adapter have like a narrowing in the same position of the picture I attached to the answer? If so just tape it, in order to trick the computer that the SD is R/W and not Read only. 

Edit: if this solved, consider accepting the answer. Also, maybe put a photo of your SD-card adapter in the post, so that it will be easier for other to find the proper solution, if mine is not working.

Comment: wait, this is the microsd, not the microsd to sd *adapter*. Does your notebook accept microSD cards?

Comment: Ok, then Add this info (the usb card reader) to the post, so that others will be able to answer in case I cannot give a solution. Silly Question: does windows recognize the usb reader? (Check right clicking on the computer icon and select **Manage** and then **Manage devices** option on the left of the window that was opened)
Another issue I found looking at your question is the sdcard name you provided: [HTS545050A7E680GR2O](https://www.cnet.com/products/hgst-travelstar-z5k500-hts545050a7e680-hard-drive-500-gb-sata-6gb-s/) is an HDD, not sd-card

Comment: when I goto Properties and then select Hardware tab, I get 4 Items in the list. Which one is for the SD Card? https://ibb.co/drQpMpm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190569/discussion-between-saumitra-topinkatti-and-pittix).

Comment: I guess it's *Generic Multi-Card device*, but that's not what I asked, but I may have made a mistake explaining. You can also open the Device Manager going in the start menu and searching "device manager", like here https://msegceporticoprodassets.blob.core.windows.net/inline-media/f97cadd8-efd7-44a6-8996-c25f4c153bdd-en

then look if anything has a yellow triangle